# android - How to merge and move text around on image

Tags: android, graphics

hi
Here's what i want to do.
- Open a jpg in full screen.
- Type text on the jpg.
- able to move that text where i want it positioned on the bitmap.
- moving of text must be done with a finger (not in code).

kind of like creating a personal funny Christmas card...

I find loots of example of writing text onto Bitmap
but nothing about moving that text around.

Help is needed!

*EDIT* 
- The image and added text must be saved as a new jpg with same size

Comment: im stuck! please advice a beginner (me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Draw the bitmap onto the screen,
   then draw the text onto it at an
   initial x,y (e.g. the center),
   following the examples you found.
2. Receive input events describing
   finger-dragging movements.
3. Use those input events to change
   the x,y values for drawing the text.
4. Redraw the bitmap and the text
   onto the screen, with the text being
   at the new x,y location.
5. Repeat from step 2.

Let us know if there are particular parts of this that you need more elaboration on.

Comment: Im using this example as a startingpoint: .........http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=11603...
It's tree balls that user can drag around the screen. the app has tree classes ball class, extends activity and  extends ImageView. Im playing around with the ide to replace the ball class with some kind of positioning engine for the (movable

Comment: (movable-text). The Problem is that when user is "done". The text and image must be merge together to form a new picture i cannot figure out how to do that

Comment: @Erik: this question/answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996759/android-source-code-not-working-reading-frame-buffer-through-glreadpixels

Comment: Thanks but it did not help. Im stumbling forward anyway and managed

Comment: @LarsH I finally followed your step-by-step and the [Answer workes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023549/android-how-to-get-the-image-edge-x-y-position-inside-imageview)

Comment: @Erik: Good! Glad you figured it out.